# Pure JavaScript change url loop

Tags: javascript

```js
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(".list a");
  for(var b = 0; b < list.length; b++) {
    var _list2 = document.querySelectorAll(".list2 a");
    for(var a = 0; a < _list2.length; a++) {
      list[b].href = _list2[a].href;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_a.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_b.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_c.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_d.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_e.com"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h2>Expected Result</h2>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_a.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_b.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_c.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_d.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_e.com"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How to replace “.list a empty hyperlinks with .list2 hyperlinks” through loop? I am puzzled with this loop. When I am using this loop, I am getting the last hyperlink for all hyperlinks. How to figure this out?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need the CDATA comment anymore.

Comment: When you get something a bit mystifying like that, a good idea is to add some console.logs and watch what actually happens. Usually it'll help you see the logic flaws because you can trace the code paths. Or step through it with your browser's debugger. Anyway, the issue is the second (inner) loop will run 5 times (so 25 iterations in all), because it runs once for each item in the outer loop. So it assigns the last hyperlink in the inner loop to whatever the current hyperlink in the outer loop is. You don't actually need the inner loop at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".list a");
var _list2 = document.querySelectorAll(".list2 a");
for(var b = 0; b < list.length; b++) {
  list[b].href = _list2[b].href;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the inner loop as you are just wanting to replace the href of the element at the same index in the first list as the second one:

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".list a");
var _list2 = document.querySelectorAll(".list2 a");

if (list.length === _list2.length) {             // check arrays are same length
  for (var a = 0; a < list.length; a++) {
    list[a].href = _list2[a].href;               // you just want to replace the href at the same index
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_a.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_b.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_c.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_d.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_e.com"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are always getting the last link from the second list is because you are looping through every item in the second list, for every item in the first list. The value that will be set will always be the last one in the loop: the last item in the second list.

What you need to do is to loop through only the first list, and use the same index to access the elements in the second list. You need to make sure that the second list is at least as long as the first.

Additionally, as evolutionxbox mentioned in their comment: you do not need the CDATA comment (in HTML and JS).

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.list a');
var list2 = document.querySelectorAll('.list2 a');
if (list.length <= list2.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[i].href = list2[i].href;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_a.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_b.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_c.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_d.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_e.com"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go thru one loop

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".list a");
var _list2 = document.querySelectorAll(".list2 a");
if (list.length === _list2.length) {
  for (var a = 0; a < _list2.length; a++) {
    list[a].href = _list2[a].href;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using the spread operator `...` and `forEach`.
(CSS used only to print the value of the `href` attribute)

```js
var l1_a = [...document.querySelectorAll('.list a')];
var l2_a = [...document.querySelectorAll('.list2 a')];

l2_a.forEach(function(el, i) {
   l1_a[i].href = el.href;
});
```

```css
a[href^=http]::before {
   content: attr(href);
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_a.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_b.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_c.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_d.com"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.sample_e.com"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do it like this

HTML

```
<div class="list">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">e</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="list2">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="https://www.sample_a.com">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.sample_b.com">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.sample_c.com">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.sample_d.com">4</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.sample_e.com">5</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".list a");
  for(let b = 0; b < list.length; b++) {
    const _list2 = document.querySelectorAll(".list2 ul a");
    list[b].href = _list2[b].href;
  }
```